# Resetting frozen I2C bus using dev adapter

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded

I am using an kontron embedded computer to to communicate to an ST micro controller over I2C. I'm using the dev adapter to interface with the I2C, using the simple read() and write() functions described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface).

The problem is if the slave fails to acknowledge a byte for whatever reason, the I2C bus freezes and the master can't send or receive any info (even if the programme is closed and restarted!). The only way I can at the moment reset the I2C bus is by rebooting, which is far from ideal.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I could do? Is there a way of comunicating over I2C using other methods which can gracefully deal with the communication failing without freezinng? Or any way in which the I2C can be reset?

Comment: The "trick" is to send nine clock. A simple search for "reset an I2C device" will give you multiple links. For instance: https://community.nxp.com/thread/316813

Comment: The problem we have is that we are using linux system reads and writes to an open filehandle. So how do we send a reset given that we cannot control special states like a line up or line down voltage for 6 ms or whatever. Some devices NEED to be reset. For example i2c routers, get stuck in a mode, and you can't change their output until you reset them. Essentially the device disappears and becomes "invisible".

Answer (score 1):

Recent kernels support I2C recovery at driver level (see [5f9296ba21b3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5f9296ba21b3c395e53dd84e7ff9578f97f24295)) and this recovery should be triggered automatically.   You might have to implement the recovery methods for your kernel and/or add the required definitions of the scl/sda gpios to the devicetree.

Answer (score 0):

The most common I2C bus error is slave device that have ended up in a state where "Data Line" is low. To recover bus, the master device should generate clock till "Data Line" goes high.

Comment: Terribly sorry for disappearing of the side of the planet for a bit. I wanted to ask though, how do you individually control the clock line? The dev adapter doesn't provide that functionality, and I've never controlled a pin single pins in a linux enviornment before, only on a micro-controller where one sets pins by writing to registers. 

Are there similarly device specific registers one can right too? Or is there another layer of abstraction provided by the linux OS, below the i2c dev adapter, one can use to individually control the lines?